# Read data with PHP and PDO_OCI

Tags: php, oracle, base64, charset

I am connecting to an Oracle database from PHP, oracle version 19 and php 8, everything works perfectly, but I have a problem when trying to read clob data, in principle, they are saved without problem from php, but when I try to read them generates inconsistency in some data (Almost all works fine), What I save in the clob field is an html text, which has some images encoded in 64, they are usually small images and text, the text loads without problem, but some images (Not all) are cut off, I have seen that the problem seems to be when reading the column from php, it seems that it does not decode the characters well and transforms them into different ones.

As an additional fact, if you removed the encoding from the following connection string,

```
$tns = " 
            (DESCRIPTION =
                (ADDRESS_LIST =
                  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = $host)(PORT = 1521))
                )
                (CONNECT_DATA =
                  (SERVICE_NAME = $db)
                )
              )
                   "

$conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$tns.";charset=AL32UTF8",$userdb,$password);
```

Everything works perfectly, the bad thing is that the text comes out with unknown characters. I cannot change the encoding of the DB since it is part of the client with other data. Its code is as follows:

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252
```

Comment: CLOB is not for binary data. Use BLOB instead

Comment: If you are talking about Base64, it uses just common ASCII symbols, so it doesn't matter what unicode codepage do you use.

Comment: Update your question with a runnable example that shows the data truncation and data change problems.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by changing the connection type, I like to use PDO, but with OCI I don't know how to read a clob properly, my opinion is that the stream_get_contents has a bug when reading this type of fields. The solution was to use OCI without PDO. If you know an alternative to stream_get_contents in PDO to read clob ("resource") type fields, I would like to know the method. The strange thing is that the system works by reading only strings, but if you add a data type code64 to it, it tends to generate errors.

**Failed with:**

```
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
$result->bindColumn(1, $TXT_ES, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$result->bindColumn(2, $TXT_CAT, PDO::PARAM_LOB);*/
$x = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
$json[] = array(
    "TXT_ES" => stream_get_contents($TXT_ES), 
    "TXT_CAT" => stream_get_contents($TXT_CAT)
);
return $json;
```

**Is ok with:**

```
$stmt = oci_parse($conOCI, $sql);
oci_execute($stmt) or die ("Unable to execute query\n");
while ( $row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt) ) {
   $json[] = array(
            "TXT_ES" => $row['TXT_ES']->load()."\n",
            "TXT_CAT" => $row['TXT_CAT']->load()."\n"
        );
        
    }
return $json;
```

Apparently load() fetches the exact data and stream_get_contents fails with the encoding type. The best way to test what I am telling you is to save a complete web page and try to read it with these two methods, if that web page has images inserted with code64, you will notice that the last method is not entirely reliable.

Comment: I do recommend OCI8 over PDO_OCI for various reasons.  You can use `OCI_FETCH_LOBS` so you don't need to call `load()`.  And you can enable LOB prefetching which can really help performance in many cases.  Check the 'USING LARGE OBJECTS IN OCI8' chapter in [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf) and see [OCI8 3.2 for PHP 8.1: New LOB prefetching feature for performance](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/oci8-32-for-php-81-new-lob-prefetching-feature-for-performance).